# How to select and save my components ids in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, react-hooks

I have a landing Page with an array that is passed to my TemplateList component. And my TemplateList component is made up by TemplateCard components.

Each card on my TemplateList can be selected, and if more than 2 of those cards are selected, the button on the page activates onOnboardingComplete, and it continues to the next page.

What I would like to do, is to be able to grab each card's unique Id that I selected on the page  And once I select one or more, convert those ids into an array (called: selectedTemplatesIds) that I can pass to onOnboardingComplete (the button).

Using the id as an identifier, and based on that we are getting an array of selected cards and passing it with onOnboardingComplete.

I hear I can use Object.keys, but never done this before. How can I do this?

Summary:

**1. I want to be able to grab my card unique ids when selected and ignore them when unselected**

**2. Once I select one or more, convert those ids into an array (selectedTemplatesIds) in order to pass them to onOnboardingComplete (the button in TemplateList).**

Here is the array I use in my LandingPage

```
    templates = [
        {
            title: "Grocery List",
            description: "Description of what this things does so the reader can have info of",
            imgURL: "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753993/groceries.png",
            id: 0,
        },

        {
            title: "Shopping Space",
            description: "blablabalblabla",
            imgURL: "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753766/shopping.png",
            id: 1,
        },

        {
            title: "Travel Planning",
            description: "blablabalblabla",
            imgURL: "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753885/travel.png",
            id: 2,
        },

        {
            title: "Travel",
            description: "blablabalblabla",
            imgURL: "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753993/groceries.png",
            id: 3,
        },
    ];
```

My Templateslist component:

```
export type Template = {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    imgURL: string;
    id?: number;
};

type Props = {
    templates: Template[];
    onOnboardingComplete: Function;
};

const TemplateList = ({ templates, onOnboardingComplete }: Props) => {
    const { aspectRatio, vmin } = useWindowResponsiveValues();

    const [noOfSelectedCards, setNoOfSelectedCards] = useState(0);

    const handleSelect = () => setNoOfSelectedCards(noOfSelectedCards + 1);
    const handleDeselect = () => setNoOfSelectedCards(noOfSelectedCards - 1);

    let buttonText;
    if (noOfSelectedCards === 1) {
        buttonText = "Select at least 1 more option";
    } else if (noOfSelectedCards >= 2) {
        buttonText = "Create my initial cuadds!";
    } else {
        buttonText = "Select at least 2 options";
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className={styles.scrollContainer}>
                {templates.map((item) => (
                    <TemplateCard
                        title={item.title}
                        description={item.description}
                        img={item.imgURL}
                        classNameToAdd={styles.cardContainer}
                        key={item.id}
                        onSelectCard={handleSelect}
                        onDeselectCard={handleDeselect}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
            <MenuButton
                onClick={onOnboardingComplete}
                style={actionButton}
                className={
                    noOfSelectedCards >= 2 ? `${styles.actionBlue}` : `${styles.actionNormal}`
                }
            >
                {buttonText}
            </MenuButton>
        </>
    );
};

export default TemplateList;
```

And my TemplateCards:

```
type Props = {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    img: string;
    classNameToAdd?: string;
    classNameOnSelected?: string;
    onSelectCard: any;
    onDeselectCard: any;
};

const TemplateCard = ({
    title,
    description,
    img,
    classNameToAdd,
    classNameOnSelected,
    onSelectCard,
    onDeselectCard,
}: Props) => {
    const { aspectRatio, vmin } = useWindowResponsiveValues();
    let className = `${styles.card} ${classNameToAdd}`;

    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = () => {
        setSelected(!selected);
        if (selected) {
            onDeselectCard();
        } else {
            onSelectCard();
        }
    };

    if (selected) {
        className += `${styles.card} ${classNameToAdd} ${classNameOnSelected}`;
    }



    return (
        <div style={card} className={className} onClick={handleClick}>
            <img style={imageSize} src={img}></img>
            <div style={cardTitle}>
                {title}
                {selected ? <BlueCheckIcon style={blueCheck} className={styles.blueCheck} /> : null}
            </div>
            <div style={descriptionCard}>{description}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

TemplateCard.defaultProps = {
    classNameOnSelected: styles.selected,
};

export default TemplateCard;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

`const selectedTemplatesIds = [];`

Change handlers:

```
const handleSelect = (id) => {
  selectedTemplatesIds.push(id);
  setNoOfSelectedCards(noOfSelectedCards + 1);
};
const handleDeselect = (id) => {
  selectedTemplatesIds.splice(selectedTemplatesIds.indexOf(id),1);
  setNoOfSelectedCards(noOfSelectedCards - 1);
  
}
```

Change:

```
<TemplateCard
                    title={item.title}
                    description={item.description}
                    img={item.imgURL}
                    classNameToAdd={styles.cardContainer}
                    key={item.id}
                    onSelectCard={() => {
                                        handleSelect(item.id)
                                  }}
                    onDeselectCard={() => {
                                        handleDeselect(item.id)
                                  }}
                />
```

Comment: Perfect! makes sense to do it this way. 

So I pass ids to the array through handleSelect, and delete the ids that I deselected through handleDeselect. 

After doing this though, how can I pass my array to my button and through my prop onOnboardingComplete (onClick={onOnboardingComplete}) in my TemplatesList?

Comment: This is my onOnboardingComplete function:

 const onOnboardingComplete = (selectedTemplatesIds) => {
  console.log("selectedTemplatesIds", selectedTemplatesIds);

  if (user.training?.level < ROOT_ITEM_ACCESSED) {
   // calls markIntroAsCompleted only the first time the onboarding gets completed
   Meteor.call("markIntroAsCompleted", () => {
    navigate("/");
   });
  } else {
   navigate("/");
  }
 };

Comment: When you setup your button's onClick handler you passed the function to it but didn't call it and that is the correct way to do it.  However, if you need to pass an argument to that function when called, you use an arrow function as the handler so `onClick={onOnboardingComplete}` becomes `onClick={() =>{ onOnboardingComplete(selectedTemplatesIds); }}`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just storing the noOfSelectedCards. Just store the array of ids:

```
const [selectedIds, setSelectedIds] = useState([]);
```

Send in the id into the handleSelect function and push the id into the array.

```
<TemplateCard
    title={item.title}
    description={item.description}
    img={item.imgURL}
    classNameToAdd={styles.cardContainer}
    key={item.id}
    onSelectCard={() => handleSelect(item.id)}
    onDeselectCard={handleDeselect}
/>

handleSelect(id) {
    setSelectedIds(prev => [...prev, id])
}
```

And you can do a similar thing to remove the id when deselecting a card.

Comment: Having selectedIds as a hook would cause additional re-renders as the handleSelect function already updates the state via `setNoOfSelectedCards`;  The selected ids themselves are irrelevant until the user completes the form thus no need to use state.

Additionally, `onSelectCard={handleSelect(item.id)}` would call the function on render creating infinite re-renders.